# Should I use cookies and sessions in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

I'm building a sample app and i've come to a point where i'm trying to create a mock shopping cart. I can successfully store a value in a cookie (the product ID) when an add to cart button is pressed but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it? The list of products I am working with is coming from a catalog API call, I'm not storing them into my own database. So my thought was to store the product id in a cookie when the button is pressed then find the other relevant data relating to the product code from the API and put it into a shopping cart row.

```
cookies[:get_prod_id] = @prod_id
```

Would using

```
session[:get_prod_id] = @prod_id
```

be better? I have the CookieStore set for the session and I see there is a _myapp_sessions cookie right when I load my app but I'm confused on how I would get the ID out of that cookie

Answer (score 1):

[Cookies](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#cookies) are always stored on the clients machine.  Where [session](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session) information is stored depends on the configuration of your app. For example, to store it the database set this in config/initializers/session_store.rb:

```
YourApp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

Run `rails g active_record:session_migration` to create the table then restart your server.

If you use the default, :cookie_store, the content will be signed so it can't be tampered with. This means it's OK to identify a user by setting a cookie for their user id. Doing this with a regular cookie would make it easy for one to pose as another user. Only use regular cookies for insensitive information that isn't specific to the current session such as the users selected language:

```
cookie[:lang] = 'en-US'
```

Comment: The default session store *is* cookies, no?

Comment: That's right. But the session cookie is just an id. The actual information is stored on the sever.

Comment: Why is session store limited to the size of cookies then? Note what it says about where the data is stored: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session. I think you're mistaken.

Comment: I didn't say session store was limited to the size of the cookies. It's stored on the server unless you use CookieStore.

Comment: *I* said it was limited to the size of cookies. The default session store is *not* on the server, but in the cookie itself. The default session cookie is *not* just an id, but the entire contents of the session. You can only advise to keep it in the session if you explicitly advise to *also* not use the recommended, default session store. Now do you get it?

Comment: Oh, I guess it's set that it's set to CookieStore by default. In this case it doesn't make much of a difference which you use. It will make it easier to change later though.